# How divide rows into columns in Tableau

Tags: layout, visualization, tableau-api

I have one dimension and two measures for showing relationship. I would like to display my dimension as shown in image attached herewith.

But unfortunately, it giving me scroll bar for vertical or horizontal display.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the scroll bars on your chart by changing the 'fit type' dropdown to 'Entire View':

[image]

Comment: dimension contains more than 20-30 values

Comment: Are you able to share a sample workbook so we can see exactly what you mean by scroll bars?

Comment: Hi as attachment not working with Stack. I will describe steps,. 
download 1. USAarrest data from R .   2. write.csv(USArrests,"usaarrest.csv") 3. Put "F1" dimension and one of the measure  in rows and one of the measure in columns . Scenario will build .

Comment: As @BenP has rightly pointed you must have Entire View even if there are 20 levels within a dimension. Tableau tries to avoid clutter , still if its more you have to opt for other kinds of Charts / or multiple sheets with various levels and collate using a Story or Dashboard.